# Need to POST data from a client application to my server

Tags: java, post, file-upload, apache-httpcomponents

I know the title is probably a common question, but I am a bit confused on everything I'm trying to do, so I am trying to piece it together, and figured a common title would be better than a confusing one.

I am basically developing a web application and one part of that is a file uploader. I am using Apache Commons File Upload via the Streaming API, and that all works fine, except I need to access the file I'm uploading, because that contains data to additional files to upload.  I.e., Read File A, get paths to images, upload images with File A to server and save on server.  The API can be found here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html

I was told there is a security risk via the web and would be impossible via a browser, since the user needs to select all files to upload, i cannot tell the browser to upload additional files, so I am left with a client side option.

I am confused if there is a special library I need, or as I have been seeing threads that talk about using the built in UrlConnection Class or http://hc.apache.org/

I basically need to be able to read the file, which technically gives me a path to a Database on the user's system which I then read to get the additional images.  After I get all of that I then  need to post the data as a multipart form as that is what the FileUpload requires.

```
form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fup.cgi">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
  Notes about the file: <input type="text" name="note"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

This is the example found in the Overview section of the Fileupload which can be accessed from the link above.

There wouldn't be an issue if the users uploaded all of the data themselves, but since I have to do some of it automatically it causes some "concerns/issues."

Basically these files are created and packaged from another application, so the images, and the db will always be in the same place, and that file that they are uploading is a file the other program creates, so everything will always be known, I just need to upload it, and then POST it as enctype="multipart/form-data" So that my servlet can read it and save it on my server.

So I would appreciate it if anyone had any suggestions on where to begin my journey with this.  I have heard of a few applications like curl and wget that are used for this, but those seem to be more C based.  As mentioned earlier it seeems the httpcomponets from apache might work well, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Depending on your application you might get around the security problem in your original idea by "cheating", read the original file on the server and generate a page with an upload form for the other files with paths filled in and let the user click "Upload".

Comment: This sounds like an excellent idea.

You ask "depending on my application" so I'm curious exactly what am I depending on?

I definitely can read the application on the server, but I will have to look up on how to generate the page from my end.

Also, something which I believed I mentioned is that the file I am uploading has to read a MS Access DB, and then from the DB I get the file names.

Right now I am using UCanAccess and I am able to access the MS Access file from my own computer, but not too sure about from the user's computer itself (as this could be a security issue also possibly)?

Comment: I think for now we are going to go with the application on the client side.

I also forgot about just using FTP itself so I will probably do that instead of streaming.  I Also need to delete files, so I figure this might be the best approach.

Thanks for your suggestion though I really appreciate it!